# Реализация остановки цикла при зажатой клавиши Esc (Python)

Tags: python, while

Сама идея заключается в том что у меня есть бесконечный цикл, который манипулирует курсором мыши и для того, чтобы выйти из этого цикла мне нужно **сделать условие при котором зажатая клавиша Esc** (не имеет значения какая будет клавиша на деле), **завершала работу цикла**.
**Проблема заключается в том, что во время работы цикла, Cmd считается не активным окном.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### keyboard

Используйте модуль [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

```
import keyboard
keyboard.wait("esc")
print("Escape!")
```

Активно ли окно или нет - не имеет значения. Он поймает нажатие.

### Пример с циклом

```
# 7621ec305801.py
# Date: December 23th, 2020.
import keyboard
import time

n = 2
IsAlive = True
def Terminate():
    global IsAlive
    IsAlive = False
keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', Terminate)

while IsAlive:
    n = 2 + (n ** 2) % 2147000000
    print('\r', n, sep='')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что `keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', Terminate)` пишется до начала цикла?

Comment: @DallasGG, да, все так. Он не как wait. Программа продолжает выполнение и встречает цикл.

Comment: @DallasGG, [add_hotkey](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey).